# Adobe Acrobat Reader DC: strange search results

Tags: search, adobe-acrobat, adobe-reader

Adobe Acrobat Reader DC keeps producing strange search results.

A few examples:

[image]

[image]

Is it a bug?

Host OS: Windows 10.

Software version: 2020.009.20067.

Comment: Having similar issues: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5nb3i.png and https://i.stack.imgur.com/7hRVv.png

Comment: @ThomasWeller FYI: new [issue](https://superuser.com/q/1702595/295913).

Answer (score 1):

In the search box, click on the settings icon and open extended search.
You just need to open it - nothing else - and it will fix the search results.

Tested with Adobe Reader DC 2021.011.20039

Screenshot (German, sorry, maybe someone can replace it):
[image: Open extended search]