# Adobe Acrobat Reader DC: why search produces irrelevant results?

Tags: search, adobe-acrobat, adobe-reader

Problem:

[image]

Version:

[image]

Adobe [Feature Request/Bug Report Form](https://www.adobe.com/products/wishform.html) does not respond after selecting "Adobe Acrobat Reader for Windows and Mac" (20210915):
[image]

Relevant question: [Adobe Acrobat Reader DC: strange search results](https://superuser.com/q/1570504/295913).

UPD20211014: "strict" != "struct":
[image]
Document: C++ International Standard, n4849.pdf, PDF Producer: pdfTeX-1.40.20.

Comment: Pull down the little gear icon Find window right side and try "Whole word only". I do that here.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't likely to be a problem with Reader at all.

The example above appears to be scanned and [OCR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition):d, in which case the search results will very much depend on the OCR process itself. If it identifies words incorrectly, the search results will be incorrect.

This [Adobe Forum thread](https://community.adobe.com/t5/acrobat-reader-discussions/adobe-reader-search-problem/td-p/1964912) discusses the issue with possible solutions.

Comment: Interesting idea. However, the example above is taken from non-scanned document. The PDF producer of that document is "Acrobat Distiller Command 3.0 for HP-UX A.09.01 and later (HPPA)".

Comment: Oh! Looks like a scan here. I still think that's an issue with the PDF, not Reader - that version of Distiller is old enough to have teenage kids by now :-D Does the user have this problem also with documents produced with tools of this millennium?

Comment: FYI: The document is ISO/IEC 9899:2011, authored by JTC 1/SC 22/WG 14 and shipped to the customer. I don't think that ISO ships scanned documents. Also: it has working and correct bookmarks used for quick navigation within the document. I don't think that scanned documents have a working and correct bookmarks.

Comment: See UPD20211014.

Comment: the linked forum thread also suggests some had a problems with the "fast find" cache ( Menu Edit -> Preferences -> Search ->Purge Cache Contents in  "Fast Find" Section. )