# Adobe Acrobat Reader DC: searching the whole word may not work

Tags: search, adobe-acrobat, adobe-reader, adobe-reader-dc

Searching the whole word does not work neither in "Find":
[image]

nor in "Full Acrobat Search":

[image]

To compare: in ST4 it works as expected:

[image]

Is it a bug?

Host OS: Windows 10, 64-bit.

Software version: 2021.011.20039, 64-bit.

---

UPD. Another case:
[image]

Comment: None of those examples except the last shows SUBNORM as a whole word, it's always part of a larger string, eg HAS_SUBNORM

Comment: I consider this an edge case. Where does a word start and end? We usually don't consider punctuation like `.,;:`. Now, whether `_` is punctuation may be debatable. If I were Acrobat, I'd probably say "works as defined by our internal criteria and the requirements engineering we have done".

Comment: @ThomasWeller Does "whole word" equal to "exact match"?

Comment: Apparently, Adobe considers underscore (_) a "white space" character. *Advanced* search engines let you specify which "white space" to accept (e.g., NBSP, hyphen, etc.) as demarcating a word. or using the NOT Boolean operator to prevent inclusion of words with an underscore, or regular expressions (REGEXP). IMHO, I'd rather have *Search* be more inclusive rather than less, since I'm the ultimate arbiter and want to see all variations.

Comment: @ThomasWeller What about `+`? See UPD.